# make a call in iphone from my application

Tags: iphone, call

how can i make call from my application to particular no. 
Give me some logic or code for performing this task...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use UIApplication's `openURL:` method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:
       [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@",phoneNumber]]];
```

Comment: thx for giving code. it's working for make a call but when the call ends then the application also terminates and again I have to initialized the application why is it so ??

Comment: alas, is iphone os limitation - it did not support multitasking for 3rd party apps before iOS4, so application gets closed when phone calls. On iOS4 it should simply go to background I think.

Comment: Just in case you're not on iPhone or you actually want feedback from your simulator, I'd recommend looking at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732043/make-calls-from-iphone-app/9732924#9732924