# How to call from a list of numbers automatically?

Tags: ios, swift

I have some phone numbers in swift , when I push the button I want it's calling to the numbers one by one, if the first number ignored or rejected it's try to calling the second one till end.
how is it possible ?

```
func insertNewObject(sender: AnyObject) {
    let contactPickerViewController = CNContactPickerViewController()
    contactPickerViewController.predicateForEnablingContact = NSPredicate(format: "contact != nil")
    contactPickerViewController.delegate = self
    presentViewController(contactPickerViewController,animated: true, completion: nil)

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) {

   self.contacts.append(contact)
    tblContacts.reloadData()
    navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call phone numbers from your app by calling `openURL` on `UIApplication`'s `sharedApplication` with a URL of the scheme "tel:###..." where "###..." is your number.:
[make a call in iphone from my application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385901/make-a-call-in-iphone-from-my-application)

After you do this, you will get no feedback to your app about whether or not the call went through.

Therefore, what you want to do is actually impossible on iOS.  There is no way to get feedback about whether or not a call went through, so there is no way to know whether/when to try the next number in the list automatically.

Comment: thnx for your reply, so there is no way to calling them one by one automatically?

Comment: Nope, as you can see from my answer.